# No Temperature in an Expanding Universe?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, temperature, space-expansion

The statistical definition of temperature as $\bigg(\dfrac{\partial \ln \Omega}{\partial E}\bigg)^{-1}$ inherently assumes the existence of a well-defined energy. To my understanding, a well-defined concept of energy stems from the time-translational symmetry according to the Noether theorem. In an expanding universe, the time-translational symmetry and thus, the existence of a genuinely conserved energy should be jeopardized. In such a scenario, does the existence of the temperature should also be re-examined? Is there any formulation of statistical mechanics that takes into account the expansion of the universe? If so, how does the notion of temperature get revised?

Comment: Why should the universe have a well-defined global temperature? OTOH, practically speaking, the temperature of the CMB (in the frame where it's isotropic) is the dominant term in the universe's temperature.

Comment: @PM2Ring No, I am not saying it should have a global temperature. And my argument is not about any such global temperature not being well defined. I am saying that since the translation of time itself is only an approximate symmetry (at best) in an expanding universe, the existence of the temperature of any system might not be really well-defined.

Comment: I think it isn't that the temperature isn't defined. Rather, the temperature is not constant in time. Seems like you can always compute the derivative of Omega for a given moment in time.

Comment: There is [Gibbons-Hawking temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbons%E2%80%93Hawking_effect) if there is a cosmological horizon.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with defining the temperature in that way, but I think the point is moot. In the derivation of the Unruh/Hawking/etc. temperature, the temperature is defined by the local occupancy of modes of some quantum field, such as the electromagnetic field.

For example, we typically show that the occupancy of photon modes follows a Bose-Einstein distribution with temperature parameter $T$. That means that for all intents and purposes the temperature *is* $T$, in the sense that any thermometer you place in the field is going to read $T$. The more general point is that a temperature measurement is a local thing, so one doesn't have to worry about global issues like the one you raise.

Comment: Interesting. I need to give some thought to the locality argument. But just to clarify my question against any potential confusion, although I am referring to the expansion of the "universe", all I really want to discuss is the notion of temperature for the usual systems and not any necessarily the cosmological systems. Invoking the expansion is simply for the purpose of saying that the time translational symmetry is broken.

Comment: Now, if we invoke the locality argument, does it essentially say that since you can always have a time translational symmetry in the small enough region of space-time, you can define a notion of temperature within that local region at once to the accuracy granted by how small your region is compared to the scale set by the cosmological constant.

Comment: @DvijMankad I’m really not sure, but I suppose it may work out; it certainly sounds plausible. The only thing I’m sure of is that a real, mercury and glass thermometer would have a nonzero reading.

Comment: Yes there would be some reading but I think the potential issue is with the transitive property. The statistical definition ensures that if A is in equilibrium with B and B with C then A will be in equilibrium with C. With the symmetry of time translation broken, I think we can potentially ensure this transitivity only locally at best.